# Unwanted padding in layout

Tags: android

I'm new in the android programmation world and I'm facing some layout design problems.
There is a padding in the layout containing the two images, see the red arrow:

http://www.servimg.com/view/13840630/200

As you can see I'm using the wrap_content attribute for both heigh and width, so I don't really understand why this is happening...

Here is my layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.scimoon.henri.scimoon.Game"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkBlue"
        android:id="@+id/back">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="35dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_bleu"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_bleu"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_rouge"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_rouge"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_jaune"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_jaune"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_vert"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bt_vert"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0):

inside your res folder there is a folder called values inside there should lie a file called dimens.xml 
open that and you will find your margins set them both too 1dp or 0dp

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. Here is my dimens.xml:

`<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="bt_size">120dp</dimen>
</resources>`

I have the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` on both your LinearLayouts containing the circles.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but with your solution I have an other problem in landscape mode:

http://i59.servimg.com/u/f59/13/84/06/30/screen11.png

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: Well, you can see that the two first circles are bigger than the two in the bottom. I would like the same size for all of them. And If I let the weight = 1, there is no problem in landscape mode

Comment: Then is there a reason why you can't centre the images vertically and horizontally instead of removing the padding?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do it: the layouts are wrapping the content, so I can't put a vertical center on the buttons, and for the layouts themselves, I just don't know wich property to use :/ I tried `layout_gravity="center"` on both but nothing changes.

Comment: Add `android:gravity="center"` on your LinearLayouts.